# Running Azure migrate in a third party data center

Tags: azure, migrate

Our customer would like to migrate from on premise to Azure.

They currently host their data in a third party data center in UK

They have asked us to run the Azure migrate tool to assess the environment in the third party data center

The third party data center has concerns that running the Azure migrate tool will allow us to see data of other customers. They also have other security and pe foreman ce concerns

How can we provide guarantees that running Azure migrate will not allow us to see data of other customers and will not cause any performance issues.?

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Migrator can’t see the customer data. It helps you identify the Azure suitability of on-premises VMs, get right-sizing recommendations and cost estimates for running the VMs in Azure.